# Is it possible to transfer ownership of chrome extension from one domain to another group account?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I published an app as unlisted under one domain (Example: @testenv.com). Many users have started using the extension already. But now I need to transfer the extension to a group account (example: @publishingGroup.com) without loosing those users and their data.

Is it possible to transfer the ownership of my extension ? or is there any way I do not lose these users ?

Comment: hi is it affect existing customers or payments we're receiving?

Answer (score 3):

There's an official [request form for account transfer request](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer) by the chrome webstore. You'll be asked to pay $5 for the new destination account.